# Angular environment circular dependency

Tags: angular

As described by the documentation, I use multiple `environment` files to parameterize the application startup.

`environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    module: ProductionModule,
    baseUrl: ...
}
```

`environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    module: DevelopmentModule
}
```

Inside `ProductionModule` I'd like to "get" a remote API URL from the `environment` module.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        LoggerModule.forRoot({ level: NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR })
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
        { provide: API_BASE_URL, useValue: environment.baseUrl }
    ]
})
export class ProductionModule {}
```

However this produces a `Circular dependency` error.
What's the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have any moduje in environment file??

Comment: @Antoniossss what do you mean?

Comment: Which module have you imported environment ?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani I've used `environment` only inside `ProductionModule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `providers` nor modules to get anything from `environment`.

Just simply import `environment.baseUrl` where you actually need it in code.

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

and in code just

`environment.baseUrl`

This will save you from circular dependency (I mean in your case - not in general), and seeing ANY MODULE in environment file is a code smell to me.

Comment: Is this the most correct way? I mean, I'd like to avoid having `environment` everywhere. An injected dependency sounds better

Comment: Thats the how-it-ment-to-be-used-way but how you do this is up to you.

Comment: What about creating another Module, say `ApiModule`, and `provide` the dependency there? I'd have only to include `ApiModule` in the `ProductionModule` imports.

Comment: The problem is that you in `AnyModule` you are importing `environment` which imports `AnyModule` - thats circular dep. Break it somehow.

Comment: This is the best way to do it

Comment: Antonios, I use much more imported modules in the `DevelopmentModule`, that's why I'm parameterizing it. Is there another way?

Comment: I would parametrize module based on env (if needed) not switch them directly in env file. Switching them on configuration level based on env could work, but I never did that so idk.

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks again

Comment: @Antoniossss could you maybe post an example of how you parameterize imported modules?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, this is what happens (`=>` means depends on):

```
environment.ts/environment.prod.ts =>
DevelopmentModule/ProductionModule =>
environment.ts/environment.prod.ts (because, in providers array, you are using environments
```

So, as you can see above, how it's generating circular dependency.

The right way depends on you, how you want to achieve it.

One way could be, to remove `module` entry from `environments`, if you are not using it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ApiProvider Service in that service import environment. create functions which you need in your project related to backend APIs. and use this ApiProvider  service anywhere in your project.